# Is it safe to run mongock with a continuously running application?

Tags: mongock

We have an application that runs as a 24x7 service in Kubernetes, and we can't take it down to run our migration scripts. I just want to verify that the mongock framework won't interfere with our application's operations - for instance, by locking a collection for an excessively long period of time.

I know the question sounds very broad, as the impacts/effects of a migration depend on the code we write in our ChangeLog/ChangeSets.

But I'm wondering whether the mongock framework itself has any effect on mongo collections other than its own internal collections (mongockChangeLog and mongockLock)

For instance, does mongock hold any locks on mongo collections other than its own?

I'm assuming that the lock owned by mongockLock won't have an effect on any collection other than mongockChangeLog.

Likewise, when transactions are enabled, does mongock own any transactions that might impact or affect the transactions owned by our code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your institution is right. Mongock's lock is just internal. Also it's worthy knowing that you can configure how long this lock is taken for, how long Mongock waits for it, if it cannot acquire it and how long it will be trying. All that it's in the [Mongock's documentation](https://www.mongock.io/)

Speaking about the transactions, Mongock delegates completely the transaction to the underneath framework. I don't fully understand your question,  but I can explain which type of transactions are offered by Mongock and you can have a better understanding of the impact.

- **All or nothing**: The entire Mongock process is wrapped in a transaction, if it fails at any point, the entire migration is rolled back.(**currently provided**)
- **Per changeSet**(method): Every changeSet successfully executed is committed. If it fails in the middle, it's rolled back.(**Will be provided in version 5**)
- **Per changeLog**(class): The entire changeLog class is wrapped in a transaction, so it will be committed only if all its changeSets are successfully executed.(**Will be provided in version 5**)

General speaking, the recommended way to organise your migrations is per changeLog. A changeLog should represent a migration step, it shouldn't be designed in a feature approach. For example if you have in your model Client and Bill, you shouldn't design a changeLog for Client and another for Bill, having in them the different migration you apply over the time. Instead, you should do it in such a way that a changeLog represent a migration step, affecting the entire model, so you can identify your migration history through your changeLogs.
From this point of view, Mongock's best practice is to use **per changeLog** transactions

Comment: Thanks! The mongock locking behavior is what we want. On transactions, we can live with an 'all or nothing' transaction for the entire migration.